# How to resolve types into a primitives in AST parser

Tags: go, code-generation

I want to extract signatures of functions to be able generate some wrapper methods over them. For this, I'm using
`golang.org/x/tools/go/packages` which provides me a possibility to read AST.

For example, for the function `func MyFunc(param int)` definition, you receive some

```
ast.FuncDecl{
    Type: *FieldList{
        List: []*Field{
            {
                Names: []*Ident{ /*...*/ },
                Type:  nil, /*...*/
            },
        },
    },
}
```

Where Type represents a type.

I want to generate some special code for all `int` parameters, but int can be also hidden with some type declaration

```
type MyType int
```

How can I convert `ast` type to the real one that the compiler has?

Comment: Can you try to be more precise? What do you want to convert into what? What do you mean by *"convert "ast" type to the real one that the compiler has"*?

Comment: @mkopriva:  I receive AST of the code using `packages.Load` function  ( i load some package - find some functions there and write wrappers over them )  . So on this step i am able to have a list of function signatures . For function `func MyFunc(param1 MyType)`   i will receive as a type of `ast.Ident("MyType")`  ( this what i  name AST type )  . But we have the other string somewhere : `type MyType int` - and this what i want to have : param1 has a type : "MyType"  which can be resolved to the int type .

Comment: Each package loaded with `packages.Load` has a `TypesInfo` field, this field will be populated if you used `packages.NeedTypesInfo` in the load mode. The `TypesInfo` field's type is declared [here](https://pkg.go.dev/go/types@go1.17.1#Info) and you can use its `Defs` field with the `*ast.Ident("MyType")` to get the type's definition. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: To fix my previous comment a bit... you also need `packages.NeedTypes` load mode, and you need to use the `Types` field instead of the `Defs` field. Try running this: https://play.golang.org/p/93-DNIxPoMk (on playground it doesn't work due to "go.mod update" or something), executed on my machine the output is as follows: https://imgur.com/zyZ7pRM.

Comment: please can you provide a minimal reproducible example. Something that loads a bit of code, parses it, and tries to use the result to get some info. My understanding is that you need to deal with types package more than ast. https://pkg.go.dev/go/types As mkopriva suggested.

Comment: @mh-cbon actually mkopriva answered to the question and https://play.golang.org/p/93-DNIxPoMk is exatly what i wanted to do. My problem was that i have not used Types and pure AST only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`packages.NeedTypes`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/go/packages#NeedTypes) and [`packages.NeedTypesInfo`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/go/packages#NeedTypesInfo) to the load mode. With that each loaded package will have its [`TypesInfo`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/go/packages#Package.TypesInfo) field initialized, and that field's type [`*types.Info`](https://pkg.go.dev/go/types#Info) has a field called [`Types`](https://pkg.go.dev/go/types#Info.Types) which maps ast expressions to types. You can use that in the following way:

```golang
func main() {
    loadConfig := new(packages.Config)
    loadConfig.Mode = packages.NeedSyntax | packages.NeedTypes | packages.NeedTypesInfo
    loadConfig.Fset = token.NewFileSet()
    pkgs, err := packages.Load(loadConfig, "syscall")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, pkg := range pkgs {
        for _, syn := range pkg.Syntax {
            for _, dec := range syn.Decls {
                if fd, ok := dec.(*ast.FuncDecl); ok && fd.Name.Name == "Kill" {
                    x1 := fd.Type.Params.List[0].Type // int
                    x2 := fd.Type.Params.List[1].Type // syscall.Signal

                    tv1 := pkg.TypesInfo.Types[x1]
                    tv2 := pkg.TypesInfo.Types[x2]

                    if basic, ok := tv1.Type.(*types.Basic); ok {
                        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", basic) // int
                    }

                    if named, ok := tv2.Type.(*types.Named); ok {
                        fmt.Printf("%v\n", named.Obj())         // *types.TypeName (Signal)
                        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", named.Underlying()) // *types.Basic (int)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think OP should be guided towards https://pkg.go.dev/go/types#AssignableTo / https://pkg.go.dev/go/types#ConvertibleTo / https://pkg.go.dev/go/types#Comparable and https://pkg.go.dev/go/types#pkg-variables to help to deal with its problem description. But i admit i am not so certain which one could be uses to loop over the definitions and test them to, for example, extract all `~~int` parameters.